# Issue installing libxml2 with homebrew on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: libxml2, homebrew

I'm trying to install libxml2 for the first time with homebrew on OSX Mountain Lion, but I'm running into the following issue

```
brew install libxml2
==> Downloading ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0 --without-python
==> make
==> make install
Error: No such file or directory - /private/tmp/libxml2-Nsul/libxml2-2.8.0/Copyright
```

Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I already had 2.7.8 installed but brew upgrade libxml2 installed 2.8.0 without issue.

Comment: @jrwen, I've amended the question to indicate this is the first attempt to install libxml2, not an upgrade. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed here
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16008

Comment: Verified. `brew update;brew install libxml2` now works correctly for new installs.